# How to convert english to arabic text in FPDF

Tags: php, fpdf

I am using FPDF api to get pdf documents  but i am using english text in html format to create pdf is there is possible to convert english words to arabic in fpdf i tried but i was not able to get it any? anyone help will be highly appreciated

Here's my code

```
<?php

$pdf=new PDF_HTML();

$pdf->AliasNbPages();
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true, 15);

$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',14);
$pdf->WriteHTML('<para><h1>Created By test Developer</h1><br>
');

$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',7); 
$htmlTable='
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="ar" dir="rtl">

<body>
<div class="trn">
<p>The Client</p>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="width:500px">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>name1</td>
            <td>name2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="width:500px">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>>&#1576;&#1610;&#1587;&#1578;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            </td>
            <td>
            <table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="width:500px">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>name1</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="width:500px">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>name1</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            </td>
            <td>
            <table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="width:500px">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>name1</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p>Your Faithfully,</p>

</div></body></html>
        ';
$pdf->WriteHTML2("<br><br><br>$htmlTable");
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',6);
```

For more code please visit http://codepad.viper-7.com/C1NSqR

Comment: This seems like a very broad, open-ended question that way it is worded.  It seems like you are basically asking "How do I localize my application?"  There are many aspects to how one might localize and application such as how am I going to get my translations (manual translations vs. machine-generated translations), how am I going to store the translations and make them available to the application, and in the case of a right to left language like Arabic, do I need different layout templates for left-to-right vs. right-to-left?